# What are the differences between the margins of the lateral and medial condyles of the tibia?

Tags: human-anatomy, anatomy

During an osteology lecture about the bones of the leg, the professor mentioned that the posterior (i think it was the posterior at least, I didn't write my notes down very well) margins of the lateral and tibial platues at the articular surface are different; the medial one's is sharper, and the lateral one's is smoother, rounder, or, as he put it, "sloppier", and this helps give more motility to the lateral meniscus and makes its injuries less likely. It also apparently helps the motion range of the knee joint.

I can't seem to be able to find any article or book that talks about this (I've checked Snell's, Gray's and Grant's anatomy books), so I was wondering if this is really a thing.

Answer (score 1):

The proximal end of the tibia is broad and flat known as tibial plateau. The intercondylar region crosses through the midline of this plateau, separating the medial and lateral condyles of the tibia.

The two condyles are in form of flat and broad surface for articulation with the medial and lateral condyles. The medial surface  is convex and subcutaneous. The lateral surface, also known as articular surface is smooth surface and somewhat concave, and articulates with the talus.

[Sources:
https://www.physio-pedia.com/Tibia
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Medial_malleolus&oldid=240146811
http://www.bartleby.com/107/61.html ]

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question; my question was about the two proximal condyles, more specifically, their posterior margins. The bartleby article does mention the fact that the posterior of the lateral plateau is slightly convex, but makes no mention of what that's good for.